# Can we call a java function from the html text-box?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, jsp, netbeans

I'm doing a web project using jsp,mysql,ajax using netbeans and mysql.
I'm having 3 textboxes, 2 is for taking the input from the user. The 3rd textbox should show the product of 2 input values.

How to do this?
Should i make a ajax call or can i call a java function in the 3 textbox.

The code is

```
<input type="text" value="" name="quantity"/>
</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="price"/>
</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="total"/>
```

In the value attribute of the textbox named "total" can i call a java function?
something like `value="getTotal()"`,but if i can how can i access the other two values.

Otherwise should i make a ajax call?

Comment: You can't call java function on your server just from the page w/o ajax or other network request.

Comment: `java` to `javascript` is like car to carpet!

Comment: since total = price * quantity I would implement it in JS but add a server-side validation upon submit - just to make sure no-one messes with your client-side code.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer what is the solution

Comment: @kirilloid what is the solution

Comment: no need of calling java function for that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to use java function...You can write client-side scripting

```
  <td><input type="text" value="" name="quantity" onblur="Calculate()"/>
  </td><td><input type="text" value="" name="price" onblur="Calculate()"/>
  </td><td><input type="text" value="" name="total"/>


  <script type="text/javascript">

  function Calculate()
  {

       var txt1 = document.getElementById("quantity");
       var txt2 = document.getElementById("price");
       var txt3 = document.getElementById("total");
       if ((txt1.value != "") && (txt2.value != ""))
       {
            txt3.value = parseInt(txt1.value) * parseInt(txt2.value); 
       }

  }

  </script>
```

Let's, keep the total textbox as a read-only or use label...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is as basic as what you are asking, you can do it with simple JavaScript.
Add the following to your script

```
function doTheMath(){
 var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
 var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
 var product = parseInt(quantity, 10) * parseFloat(price);
 document.getElementById("total").value = product;
```

}
and change your html to the following to call the javascript function whenever there is a change.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="quantity" onchange="doTheMath()"/>
```

Making a server call for simple math is not suggestable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery. With jQuery you can dynamically set the value of a text box depending on what the user types in other fields. I recently implemented this for a shopping basket I did for a client. jQuery also has a .ajax() method which is quite easy to use.

Check out these resources:

http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Sorry I do not have time to write a coded response. Hope this helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
 <TITLE></TITLE>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     function Calculate()
      {

       var txt1 = document.getElementById("FirstNo");
       var txt2 = document.getElementById("SecondNo");
       var txt3 = document.getElementById("Output");
       if ((txt1.value != "") && (txt2.value != ""))
       {
            txt3.value = parseInt(txt1.value) * parseInt(txt2.value); 
       }

      }

    </script>

 <input id="FirstNo" type="text" value="" onblur="Calculate()" style="width:50px"/> * 
 <input id="SecondNo" type="text" value="" onblur="Calculate()" style="width:50px"/>
 <input id="Output" type="text" style="width:50px"/>
 </FORM>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```